# Linux XML parser library

Tags: xml, linux

Anybody knows good Linux XML parser library available, and how to set it up and use it? Thanks.

Comment: Er, what language do you need to use this from?

Comment: I　ｐｌａｎ　ｔｏ　ｕｓｅ　Ｃ＋＋，　ｔｈｅｎ　ｕｓｅ　ＸＭＬ　ｐａｒｓｅｒ　ｔｏ　ｄｏ　ｓｏｍｅ　ｄａｔａ　ｐｒｏｃｅｓｓ．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LibXML](http://xmlsoft.org/) — it has bindings for lots of different languages, and most distributions make it available via their package repositories.

Answer (score 7):

[libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) is pretty much the standard XML parser library on Linux.

For C++, I'd recommend the [libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) bindings

Comment: Thanks Brian, it is very nice to get your suggestion.